# Returning an instance of a parameter class using generics

Tags: java, generics

This might be obvious to many of you but,

How do I convert this (example) function to using generics:

```
private Object makeNewInstance(Class clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
private <T> T makeNewInstance(T clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

But the parameter T must be a class and return T an instance of T.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the argument type to `Class<T>`:

```
private <T> T makeNewInstance(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
  return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) for more information about `Class<T>` and `newInstance()`.

Also, depending on your context, you may consider making the `makeNewInstance()` method static.

Answer (score 0):

```
private <T> T makeNewInstance(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter should still be of type `Class`:

```
private <T> T makeNewInstance(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
  return clazz.newInstance();
}
```